# Count the same id with in one single column and other column have where clause

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I have [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210354/count-the-same-id-with-group-by-in-one-single-column) just like this and have been answered.

Now, i have a new column but same table ( now with a date )

```
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| id_kondisi | id_sub_kondisi | tgl_kondisi |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 01         | 0102           | 2017-09-13  |
| 03         | 0302           | 2017-09-13  |
| 01         | 0101           | 2017-09-13  |
| 01         | 0102           | 2017-09-13  |
| 01         | 0101           | 2017-09-13  |
| 03         | 0301           | 2017-09-13  |
| 03         | 0303           | 2017-09-13  |
| 02         | 0202           | 2017-09-14  |
| 01         | 0102           | 2017-09-13  |
| 03         | 0301           | 2017-09-13  |
| 01         | 0101           | 2017-09-13  |
| 02         | 0203           | 2017-09-14  |
| 03         | 0302           | 2017-09-13  |
| 02         | 0202           | 2017-09-14  |
| 02         | 0201           | 2017-09-14  |
| 02         | 0202           | 2017-09-14  |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE kondisi
    (`id_kondisi` int, `id_sub_kondisi` int, `tgl_kondisi` date)
;

INSERT INTO kondisi
    (`id_kondisi`, `id_sub_kondisi`, `tgl_kondisi`)
VALUES
    (01, 0102, 2017-09-13),
    (03, 0302, 2017-09-13),
    (01, 0101, 2017-09-13),
    (01, 0102, 2017-09-13),
    (01, 0101, 2017-09-13),
    (03, 0301, 2017-09-13),
    (03, 0303, 2017-09-13),
    (02, 0202, 2017-09-14),
    (01, 0102, 2017-09-13),
    (03, 0301, 2017-09-13),
    (01, 0101, 2017-09-13),
    (02, 0203, 2017-09-14),
    (03, 0302, 2017-09-13),
    (02, 0202,  2017-09-14),
    (02, 0201,  2017-09-14),
    (02, 0202, 2017-09-14)
;
```

How do i make in `count_tot` will sum the number of id that had been looped and in `tgl_count1` column that contain where clause if `tgl_kondisi` is `2017-09-13`. The result i want is just like this:

```
+----------------+-------------+------------+
| kondisi_tot    | coun_tot    |tgl_count1  |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
| 01             |  6          |  6         |
| 0101           |  3          |  3         |
| 0102           |  3          |  3         |
| 02             |  5          |  0         |
| 0201           |  1          |  0         |
| 0202           |  3          |  0         |
| 0203           |  1          |  0         |
| 03             |  5          |  5         |
| 0301           |  2          |  2         |
| 0302           |  2          |  2         |
| 0303           |  1          |  1         |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
```

I have do something like, but it didnt work

```
select id, count(id), (select count(id) from kondisi where tgl_kondisi='2017-09-13') 
from 
(select id_kondisi as id from kondisi
union all
select id_sub_kondisi from kondisi) merged_table
group by id
order by cast(id as char)
```

Comment: `SELECT id, COUNT(id), SUM(CASE tgl_kondisi='2017-09-13', 1, 0)` - *conditional aggregation*.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Wrong syntax.
`SELECT id, COUNT(id), SUM(CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi='2017-09-13'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: where do i should place `tgl_kondisi`  ? it return  `Unknown column 'tgl_kondisi' in 'field list'`

Comment: You need to have it available in your derived `merged_table`

Comment: oh i got it, it works! thanks @PM77-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct query would be

```
SELECT 
     id, 
     COUNT(id), 
     SUM(
          CASE WHEN 
               tgl_kondisi='2017-09-13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM 
(   SELECT 
         id_kondisi as id,
         tgl_kondisi
    FROM kondisi
           UNION ALL

    SELECT 
         id_sub_kondisi,
         tgl_kondisi
    FROM kondisi
) 
merged_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY cast(id as char)
```

I changed my

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM kondisi WHERE tgl_kondisi='2017-09-13')`

Into

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id), SUM(CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi='2017-09-13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

and add `tgl_kondisi` in both `UNION` table

Thanks to [PM77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1)